# javascript event model

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

I am an actionscript developer. while develop a component, there is a way to listen parent's click event and refer a function inside that component.

If i add 100 components into my main application, and if i click on parent application, those 100 components call it's own function.

```
Component.as

parentApplication.addEventListener('click', ClickHandler);

function ClickHandler(event:event)
{
  ....
}
```

what is the way to achieve this samething using javascript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may use jQuery which provides similar (but not the same) event handling.  In your case, that would be like

```
$(childComponent).click(function(eventObject){
    childComponent = $(this);
    ...
});
```

or

```
$(childComponent).bind("click", function(eventObject){
     childComponent = $(this);
     ...
});
```

Note that    bind is very different from databind in Flex, and it is very much like addEventListener.  The tricky thing here is object scope.  In JavaScript (like ActionScript 2 or earlier), any time when an event is handled,     this refers to the object that raises the event, not the parent that listens to the event, which could be quite counter-intuitive.

More on [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works) can be found here, so are its [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/), [bind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) and unbind feature.

Comment: i don't want to add click event for each child component. i need each child component listen document's click event and call their own function.